# Linux Device Tree to Hardware Mapping

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-driver

I was wondering how some specific details in the device relate to the hardware and where to find this information(like schematic, datasheet etc).

An example of a usb node is given below:
[image]

In the picture above I was wondering how do you find `CLK_BUS_OHCI2` or `RST_BUS_EHCI2` on the hardware. If you go to the include files you get a value (`CLK_BUS_OHCI2 = 39`), but I am not sure how that relates to actual hardware. Like which register or which pin etc.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays I'm working with a similar platform, Allwinner A64 and I'm trying to understand how DTS, clocks, resets work. Fortunately your question came up in the search engine results. Gaurav Pathak's answer clarified most of the things for me and I want to extend a little bit from his point to help those who are trying to fill in the gap about bridging DTS and hardware.

I will refer to [Linux kernel 5.7](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/v5.7) and [Allwinner A64 User Manual (v1.1)](http://linux-sunxi.org/A64#Documentation).

There's a resemblance between `uart4` and `ehci2` in the means of node definition; for instance, we have property of `clocks` and `resets` in both of them. But `ccu` clock output usage were implemented different.

Let's take a closer look at `uart4` [node](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3d77e6a8804abcc0504c904bd6e5cdf3a5cf8162/arch/arm64/boot/dts/allwinner/sun50i-a64.dtsi#L917).

```
uart4: serial@1c29000 {
        compatible = "snps,dw-apb-uart";
        reg = <0x01c29000 0x400>;
        interrupts = <GIC_SPI 4 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
        reg-shift = <2>;
        reg-io-width = <4>;
        clocks = <&ccu CLK_BUS_UART4>;
        resets = <&ccu RST_BUS_UART4>;
        status = "disabled";
    };
```

Now we already know that [CLK_BUS_UART4](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3d77e6a8804abcc0504c904bd6e5cdf3a5cf8162/include/dt-bindings/clock/sun50i-a64-ccu.h#L93) is included from [include/dt-bindings/clock/sun50i-a64-ccu.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3d77e6a8804abcc0504c904bd6e5cdf3a5cf8162/include/dt-bindings/clock/sun50i-a64-ccu.h).

```
<&ccu CLK_BUS_UART4>
```

A further search for `CLK_BUS_UART4` reveals that [include/dt-bindings/clock/sun50i-a64-ccu.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3d77e6a8804abcc0504c904bd6e5cdf3a5cf8162/include/dt-bindings/clock/sun50i-a64-ccu.h) is also indirectly (through [drivers/clk/sunxi-ng/ccu-sun50i-a64.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3d77e6a8804abcc0504c904bd6e5cdf3a5cf8162/drivers/clk/sunxi-ng/ccu-sun50i-a64.h#L11)) included from [drivers/clk/sunxi-ng/ccu-sun50i-a64.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3d77e6a8804abcc0504c904bd6e5cdf3a5cf8162/drivers/clk/sunxi-ng/ccu-sun50i-a64.c).

Then it was possible to refer to `CLK_BUS_UART4` like below ([L807 @ ccu-sun50i-a64.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3d77e6a8804abcc0504c904bd6e5cdf3a5cf8162/drivers/clk/sunxi-ng/ccu-sun50i-a64.c#L807))

```c
    [CLK_BUS_UART4] = &bus_uart4_clk.common.hw
```

But what is `bus_uart4_clk`? Let's see.

It is defined at [L381 @ ccu-sun50i-a64.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3d77e6a8804abcc0504c904bd6e5cdf3a5cf8162/drivers/clk/sunxi-ng/ccu-sun50i-a64.c#L381). This is how it looks:

```c
    static SUNXI_CCU_GATE(bus_uart4_clk,    "bus-uart4",    "apb2",
              0x06c, BIT(20), 0);
```

`SUNXI_CCU_GATE` is a macro to manage gating register of Clock Control Unit. 4th argument, `0x06c` refers to the register offset and 5th argument `BIT(20)` implies the **N**th bit (20, in this case) at the offset of `0x06c` is adjusted to drive `bus_uart4_clk`.

[image: Allwinner A64 UART4 CCU Gating Register Description]

Same thing applies for the `resets` property. To give a specific example; just search for `RST_BUS_UART4` and `0x2d8` at Linux kernel source then look at the bottom of Page 142 of the A64 User Manual.

I hope there were not too much nonsense... Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as far as I know in the below structure

```
ehci2: usb@01c1c000 {
            compatible = "allwinner,sun8i-h3-ehci", "generic-ehci";
            reg = <0x01c1c000 0x100>;
            interrupts = <GIC_SPI 76 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
            clocks = <&ccu CLK_BUS_EHCI2>, <&ccu CLK_BUS_OHCI2>;
            resets = <&ccu RST_BUS_EHCI2>, <&ccu RST_BUS_OHCI2>;
            phys = <&usbphy 2>;
            phy-names = "usb";
            status = "disabled";
        };
```

`clocks = <&ccu CLK_BUS_EHCI2>, <&ccu CLK_BUS_OHCI2>;` represents consumer clocks i.e. input clocks and is called "phandle + clock specifier pairs". As you mentioned CLK_BUS_OHCI2 has value 39, that means USB controller will take input clock from the output 39 of `ccu` clock source.

In the `dtsi` file from where you posted the above screenshot, there should be a structure that defines the `ccu` for example like this below:

```
ccu: clk@01c20060 {
            #clock-cells = <1>;
            compatible = "allwinner,sun7i-a20-ahb-gates-clk";
            reg = <0x01c20060 0x8>;
            clocks = <&ahb>;
            clock-output-names = "ahb_usb0", "ahb_ehci0",
                "ahb_ohci0", "ahb_ehci1", "ahb_ohci1",
                "ahb_ss", "ahb_dma", "ahb_bist", "ahb_mmc0",
                "ahb_mmc1", "ahb_mmc2", "ahb_mmc3", "ahb_ms",
                "ahb_nand", "ahb_sdram", "ahb_ace",
                "ahb_emac", "ahb_ts", "ahb_spi0", "ahb_spi1",
                "ahb_spi2", "ahb_spi3", "ahb_sata",
                "ahb_hstimer", "ahb_ve", "ahb_tvd", "ahb_tve0",
                "ahb_tve1", "ahb_lcd0", "ahb_lcd1", "ahb_csi0",
                "ahb_csi1", "ahb_hdmi1", "ahb_hdmi0",
                "ahb_de_be0", "ahb_de_be1", "ahb_de_fe0",
                "ahb_de_fe1", "ahb_gmac", "ahb_ehci2",
                "ahb_mali";
        };
```

In the above structure there are multiple clock source outputs, so clock source 39 should be utilised by the above USB controller for taking clock input, note that `#clock-cells = <1>;` represents multiple clock output and `#clock-cells = <0>;` is for single clock output.
The `ccu` structure is just an example.